# Python precedence rules for boolean operators

Tags: python, boolean-expression, short-circuiting, operator-precedence

When I evaluate the following expression:

1 or (1/0) and 1

What are the rules (precedence, short-circuit evaluation etc) are followed to get the answer

Comment: This question has NOT been already asked. The question that refers to the priority of NOT AND & OR in python does not address the short circuit evaluation taking place here.

Answer (score 2):

`b or anything_else` is defined to return b if b is true-ish, without evaluating anything_else. Since your first 1 is true-ish, your 1/0 never gets evaluated, hence no error. By "true-ish" I mean any value that Python considers true, not only the `True` boolean value. Try your expression with True or [2] in place of the first 1 to see what I mean.

Comment: Can post the link to the official documentation containing this information?

Comment: For Python 2: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

Answer (score 1):

Python short-circuit evaluates. In your example, the expression

```
1 or (1/0) and 1
```

finishes evaluation at the first `1` and returns `True`.

A more minimal example serves to illustrate Python's short-circuit evaluation. Consider the expression:

```
(1/0) or 1
```

This raises a `ZeroDivisionError` exception upon evaluation of `(1/0)`. But the expression:

```
1 or (1/0)
```

short-circuit evaluates to `True`. No exception is raised since the sub-expression `(1/0)` never gets evaluated.